Как правильно вставить HTML-код в JSON-файл?
Есть JSON-файл, данные из которого должны выводиться в HTML-файле:
{
    "lineOne": "Здесь&nbsp;длинный <br> текст",
    "lineTwo": "Кликните по <a href='https://google.com'>ссылке</a>"
}

Проблема в том, что в строке 1 текст имеет неразрывный пробел &nbsp; и тег переноса <br>.
Во второй строке у нас ссылка.
Но при выводе в HTML данные выводятся, как текстовые строки, то есть HTML-теги не работают.
Как правильно записать данные, чтобы они выводились, как HTML, а не текст?

Читайте документацию к той штуке, с помощью которой вы выполняете «вывод в HTML», а JSON здесь вообще ни при чём

Зря вы вопрос так быстро удалили, я не успел потенциально полезный вам коммент отправить — если вы имеете в виду, что вам лень прописывать lang для каждого селектора в стилях, то используйте nesting или, если нужна поддержка старых браузеров, возьмите css-препроцессор

Может, Вы как-то некорректно выводите? Вроде всё работает:


let json = {
    "lineOne": "Здесь&nbsp;длинный <br> текст",
    "lineTwo": "Кликните по <a href='https://google.com'>ссылке</a>"
}
document.getElementById('wrap-1').innerHTML = json.lineOne;
document.getElementById('wrap-2').innerHTML = json.lineTwo;
<div id="wrap-1"></div>
<div id="wrap-2"></div>



